# CakePHP 3 + Counter cache + InnoDB Deadlocks

Tags: mysql, cakephp, innodb, cakephp-3.x

I hope someone can shed some light on this as I am confused as hell about it. I have recently started stress testing an API I am creating and when the requests get up to over 5 per second I start getting 80% failures with

> SQLSTATE[40001]: Serialization failure: 1213 Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction"

I understand the reason for deadlocks, I just don't understand what is causing them in a pretty long standing function of CakePHP, in my Impressions Model I have the following:

```
$this->addBehavior('CounterCache', [
        'Zones' => [
            'impressions_count'
        ],
        'Beacons' => [
            'impressions_count'
        ],
        'Devices' => [
            'impressions_count'
        ],
        'Applications' => [
            'impressions_count'
        ]
    ]);
```

So on each save I want to update impressions_count on each of those models.

If I comment out Devices and Applications it runs as expected, if I leave them in I get the following information about the deadlocks and 80% of the calls fail with the above SQL failure.

https://gist.github.com/voycey/43071349d6e1ee899444e0a4ee8ac6ed

From what I can see the deadlocks are caused by this countercache insert, what I don't understand is why? It seems a pretty simple thing to be doing. I have even coded a behaviour which does the same thing (finds the record, increments the counter and re-saves)

Edit:

I have created my own Behavior to basically emulate Counter Cache and it basically solves 90% of this by simply manually incrementing the field(s). However I have tracked the remaining 10% of errors to a potentially long running query that is called after the counter cache behaviour.

Comment: Can you provide the query?  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` ?

Comment: I've actually tracked this down to another query that is happening afterwards - im going to edit my question